# Why do unpainted areas appear in the origin lab contour plot?

Tags: plot, colors, undefined, contour, originlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Mk8.png)When I make a contour plot in originlab, some areas appear in white. This seems to be due to the fact that it is taking very large values and in the color scale it is specified that for values greater than a certain value, all are painted in white. the question is, is there a way to make the color gradient continue to the maximum value?